# How to add reference in Windowphone 7 Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.dll?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to create list picker in WP7.I have to add Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.dll  this reference.But i am unable to add it.It is not present in reference list.
Plz tell methe way to add this reference.

Answer (score 1):

Either [download and install the MSi](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/60291) to see it in the list.
Or use NuGet.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the Toolkit? http://silverlight.codeplex.com/